# Better way to pass function as argument with "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple question of what is better to do (or if at least is correct) when passing a function as argument that uses the `this`.

The better way to explain this is with an example:

Let's say I want to `fadeOut` an object and then remove it from the DOM. So I will do this:

```
$("ul li.active").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Or should I do this? Is this correct? (It works but maybe it is a bad practice)

```
$("ul li.active").fadeOut($(this).remove);
```

I didn't find anything relative to this on any question, so I want to know.

Comment: Is it possible that `$("ul li.active")` will match multiple elements?

Comment: @PatrickQ Not in my case, but what if matches multiple elements?

Comment: Am I missing something? Neither uses match the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: It doesn’t actually work; check your DOM. (It could if jQuery were a little more polite, but it doesn’t.)

Comment: Passing a callback seems to work fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/TE6Rz/

Comment: @PatrickQ: I think minitech meant the *second* example doesn't work: `$("ul li.active").fadeOut($(this).remove);` The fadeOut happens, but the element isn't removed.

Comment: @ikegami: The first one does.

Comment: @minitech was right. It was my bad.. The this was not setted by jquery at that point, so the second does not remove the object. It tries to do window.remove() I just don't know why it does not throw an error

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, The first one does what? Match the docs? Not the docs I linked. Could you provide a link?

Comment: @ikegami It absolutely is documented. And yes, in the docs that you linked. The first function signature is `.fadeOut( [duration ] [, complete ] )`. That means that both of those parameters are optional. So you can pass only the second parameter (a callback) and that's perfectly fine. The description of the second parameter is `A function to call once the animation is complete.` And further down the page, it says "The callback is not sent any arguments, but `this` is set to the DOM element being animated."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example *doesn't* work (the element fades out, but it is not removed — the callback doesn't know which element to remove, and so removes none). It fails because the `remove` function expects to be called with `this` referring to a jQuery instance, and when you set up the callback that way, it gets called with `this` referring to a DOM element instead.

In the specific case of most jQuery callbacks, your first form is the standard way to do it:

```
$("ul li.active").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The reason this is standard is that jQuery sets the value of `this` to the specific DOM element related to the event. (With some callbacks it's something other than DOM element, but that's the usual thing.)

Or of course, if you need to do that a lot, you might have a named function you can reuse:

```
function removeCallback() {
    $(this).remove();
}

$("ul li.active").fadeOut(removeCallback);
// ...elsewhere...
$("some other selector").fadeOut(removeCallback);
```

---

In the *general* case, not specifically related to jQuery, if you need to set up a method callback on a specific object (so, **you** want to be in control of what `this` is), you can use ES5's `Function#bind` to avoid creating unnecessary closures.

```
doSomethingAndCallMeBack(this.method.bind(this));
```

There, we're using `this.method.bind(this)` to create a function that, when called, will call `this.method` ensuring that `this` within the method is the same thing it means in our code. If we just did this:

```
doSomethingAndCallMeBack(this.method); // <== Can be wrong
```

...we're relying on `doSomethingAndCallMeBack` to know what `this` value to use (nothing is passed to it above to tell it, it would have to *already* know).

But since jQuery usually sets `this` to a useful value, that's slightly less common in jQuery code.

More on this (ugh, no pun) on my blog:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)